# Is there a way to dynamically set collections name on MongoDB Quarkus?

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

In Spring I'm able to use [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), and create a collection dynamically for the context of the incoming request, all I've to do is annotate the POJO with `@Document` and pass the query as a annotation parameter like:

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document("#{@bean.someMething}Customer")
public class Customer {

    // Fields || Getter || Setter
    
}
```

But I can't figure a way to easily set this on Quarkus / MongoDB.
I do not mind in using `quarkus-mongodb-client` or `mongodb-panache`.

I tough that about producing a bean with `@RequestContext` that would be responsible to create a new `MongoDatabase (com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase)` client with some info from the headers.